# How do I remove the following path that isn't found from my project?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have just upgraded to C++ Builder XE8.

When I compile a given unit, I receive the following warning twice:

```
[bcc32 Warning]
 W8123 Path 'C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Components' not found 
- path ignored in option '-I'
```

I have searched the Project and Options windows for this path, and have been unable to find it.

How can I find and remove this path setting?

Comment: For Borland Delphi, you can usually hack the project file with Notepad

Comment: That worked to find the path in question.

Comment: The `-I` option is used for setting the compiler's **Include file search path**. So the missing folder is mentioned in your project's includes path.  You can modify that field in the Project Options, there is no need to resort to editing the project file directly in Notepad.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to remove invalid path from RAD Studio XE8 is through project options dialog.

Now based on the information provided in question it seems that your `Include path` points to a non-existent directory.

So in order to edit the `Include path` open the Project Options.
Then navigate to `Directories and Conditionals` tab which is in `Resource compiler` section.

[image: Project Options Dialog]

Once there click on `Include file search path` line and later on three dotted button that shows on the right of the line.

This will open another dialog suitable for editing path entries.

[image: Path Editing Dialog]

Best advantage of this dialog is that it automatically preforms the path validation for each entry so you can quickly see which path entries are not currently valid. They can be easily recognized as being greyed.

So you can simply select the non-valid path and click on delete button to remove it.

NOTE: You can quickly remove all invalid path entries using `Delete Invalid Paths` button but I urge **caution** especially if you are modifying paths in general RAD Studio Options. Why?

Because general RAD Studio Options also include several special paths that use special folder designations like `$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports`

These folders might not exist all the time or their path could be relative to the opened project path and therefore could be marked as being invalid at the time the Path Editing dialog was open.

So simply clicking the `Delete Invalid Paths` would remove them and could cause the IDE to stop working properly.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that these settings are target platform dependant so you might have to go and modify `All Configuration` of your project

[image: Selecting Platform Options]

If that doesn't gives you suitable option then you might have to modify the general IDE option accesed through Tools->Options menu.

[image: General IDE Options]

Note that these options are again target platform specific so you might need to select proper platform.

And if that still doesn't allow you to solve your problem then it is possible that somewhere in your project you have an *.inc file which is pointing to a nonexistent folder. In such case you would have to manually modify that specific *.inc file.

Comment: One problem. Although this seems like the correct location to remove the paths, I don't have the option to remove the invalid path, because it has 'Inherit values from "Base"' checked. It seems the path is set in the 'Base' configuration. How do I modify the 'Base' values?

Comment: I have updated my answer and hope it now does provide you with enough information to solve your problem. If not then I would request you to post the contents of both *.dpr and *.dproj files here.

Comment: @SW, I tried clicking 'All Configuration', specific OS ones in that, 'Debug Configuration', ones within that, and 'Release Configuration' and ones within that. None of it seemed to allow me to remove the path in question. Hopefully, though, your answer will prove useful for other people - since it didn't actually solve the problem (but it was fixed by opening up the .proj file in Notepad), I have voted for the answer being useful.

Comment: It is possible that this is due the reason you upgraded to XE8 from older version. I do remember that I had to recreate the project instead of migrating it directly from Delphi 7 in order to be able to add 64 bit version in Delphi XE3. The cause was improper transfer of old settings to newer version. Now without seeing your original *.drp and *.dproj files I can be sure if you have experienced same problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the path error (if the same).

I created a project on the desktop and built it.  After the results I put the project in a different directory where it will not work or build any more.  But when I moved it back to the original place I can build and run it.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, you can always open the .dproj file in a text editor, search for the path in question and delete it. It might be part of some of the additional entries there that are not directly available through the GUI. Remember to make a backup of the file first, if it is not already in SCM.